# IIS hosted WCF to share data between calls

Tags: wcf, iis, caching

I have a WCF web service that returns data to the user based on provided last message received ID for the user group of the requestor. I'm looking up if there is relevant data to return in database.

I would like to speed up the response time so I would like to have "cached" list of data based on last received message id from the previous call so I would not need to look up the data in database for repeated calls every time.

Can you advice if there is a way to use say a dictionary, that would use groupID as key and value would be object containing data for that group (message ID's and relevant data).
If the data would be returned by request, I would remove it from the dictionary.

If no data would be found in dictionary I would try to fill it from database (based on last message ID from the request).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,I suggest that you can use Cache in WCF..NET Framework 4.6.1 enables you to use the declarative caching mechanism already available in ASP.NET in your WCF Web HTTP services. This allows you to cache responses from your WCF Web HTTP service operations.

To enable WEB HTTP service caching, you must first enable ASP.NET compatibility by applying the AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute to the service setting RequirementsMode to Allowed or Required.

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Also turn on ASP.NET compatibility mode in the Web.config file as shown in the following example.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

The AspNetCacheProfileAttribute attribute specifies a cache profile that contains the cache settings to be used.

```
[WebGet]
[AspNetCacheProfile("CacheFor60Seconds")]
```

The cache profile name specified by the AspNetCacheProfileAttribute identifies a cache profile that is added to your Web.config configuration file. The cache profile is defined with in a  element as shown in the following configuration example.

```
<system.web>  
   <caching>  
      <outputCacheSettings>  
         <outputCacheProfiles>  
            <add name="CacheFor60Seconds" duration="60" varyByParam="none" sqlDependency="MyTestDatabase:MyTable"/>  
         </outputCacheProfiles>  
      </outputCacheSettings>  
   </caching>  
   <!-- ... -->  
</system.web>
```

The Demo is Basic Web HTTP Service Caching,For more information about Cache in WCF,Please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/caching-support-for-wcf-web-http-services

Comment: Will this "default" caching help me if I don't want to cache response, but only to have data prepared for following requests?

Comment: I think it will help you, if subsequent requests all request the same URI, it will not query the data from the database and speed up the response time. You can check the link I gave, which has detailed instructions. I think this is a good solution.

Comment: OK, I will try it and if it will behave as I'm expecting, then I would mark your reply as an answer.

Comment: It works for one caller when he does not open new connection for each call but reuses the one he already opened. I need to share my cache object between different callers and different calls. Any ideas?